# Creating NxM indices from a Python array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I would like to take an NxM matrix, for simplicity, we'll use

```
x=np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
```

And I would like to create a new matrix, A, in which I can store a node for each element in the first row, its N-direction index in the second row, its M-direction index in the third row, and the elements actual value in the fourth row. However, I am having difficulty in finding out how to create a container which can hold all of these values without knowing their exact length ahead of time(as in the final script, some nodes in the beginning matrix will be excluded if they are under a threshold)
So, for example, something possibly like this:
(using networkx as graph/node method, documentation: http://networkx.github.io/)

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
A=[]
g=nx.Graph()
x2=np.ravel(x,order='C')
for k in x2:
    A[0,:]=g.add_node(k)
    A[3,:]=x2[k]

for i in length(x):
    for j in height(x):#also not sure how to return height/number of sub arrays
        x[i]=A[1,:]
        x[j]=A[2,:]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `np.shape(x)`? This returns a tuple containing the number of elements in each dimension of `x`. In your example, it would return `(5, 5)`.

Comment: You're going to have to make this clearer; I don't know what an N-direction or M-direction index are. And I'm not sure what you mean by storing the node in the first row either. Will the new matrix A have 4 rows and 25 columns in your example?

Comment: @NirFriedman N direction is the direction along the column axis, in this example 5, and M is row direction, also 5. However, my input matrix will not always be predefined as 5x5, it will be unknown length so I need to fetch the lengths in each direction. Addition of nodes has been corrected for clarity, as i realize i made a mistake. The new matrix A will have 4 rows, and each row will have variable length depending on the number of items it needs to store.

Comment: Can you please give a example with a small matrix? I still have no real idea what the goal of this is.

Comment: for our example above, x=np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))

A=[[node0,node1,...node24]
     [column index for each node above from 0 to 24]
     [row index for each node from 0 to 24]
     [value for each node from 0 to 24]]

Comment: Looks like `node` is a python object.  In that case your `A` array will have to have `dtype=object`.  Or maybe it could be a structured array.  But why not just make `A` a list of lists or tuples?  What do you gain by making `A` an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

```
x = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)) 
A = [[node0,node1,...node24], 
     [column index for each node above from 0 to 24], 
     [row index for each node from 0 to 24], 
     [value for each node from 0 to 24]]
```

One easy way to collect this sort of information would be loop like

```
A = []
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        if x[i,j] too small:
             continue
        a='node(%s,%s)'%(i,j),i,j,x[i,j]
        A.append(a)
```

producing a list of tuples like:

```
[('node(0,0)', 0, 0, 0),
 ('node(0,1)', 0, 1, 1),
 ('node(0,2)', 0, 2, 2),
 ('node(0,3)', 0, 3, 3),
 ...
 ]
```

It could be turned into a structured array with

```
M=np.array(A,dtype='O,i,i,f')

array([('node(0,0)', 0, 0, 0.0), ('node(0,1)', 0, 1, 1.0),
       ('node(0,2)', 0, 2, 2.0), ('node(0,3)', 0, 3, 3.0),
       ('node(0,4)', 0, 4, 4.0), ('node(1,0)', 1, 0, 5.0),
       ('node(1,1)', 1, 1, 6.0), ('node(1,2)', 1, 2, 7.0),
       ....
       ('node(4,4)', 4, 4, 24.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

and fields can be accessed with  `M['f3']` etc.

`[M['f0'],M['f1'],M['f2'],M['f3']]` produces the `A` list - a list of arrays.

A more direct way of making your list of 4 lists:

```
A = [[],[],[],[]]
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        A[0].append('node(%s,%s)'%(i,j))
        A[1].append(i)
        A[2].append(j)
        A[3].append(x[i,j])
```

You could also loop over the raveled `x`, but then you have to deduce the coordinates another way.

Comment: You're the best. A lifesaver once again.